# I Want to fetch SQL Records in MySQL of current Year

Tags: mysql

I am using the query

```
SELECT count(enq.`enquiryId`), Month(enq.`date`), Year(enq.`date`) 
FROM enquiry enq  
GROUP BY MONTH(enq.`date`)
```

But I get all year records. 
I just want to get Current or any input year(At Runtime) records.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT count(enq.`enquiryId`), Month(enq.`date`), Year(enq.`date`) 
FROM enquiry enq  
WHERE Year(enq.date)=somevalue    --2015 for example
GROUP BY MONTH(enq.`date`)
```

Comment: You should take into account that using a function inside a WHERE will not make use of any index, and is going to be a performance issue in the future when you'll have a big table. Is going to be better, (if that columns are timestamp columns) having two separate columns (one with the month and other wiht the year) to avoid using the date MySQL functions and avoid performances issues. Of course, that columns should have index to speed up the queries.

Answer (score 0):

Put where in your query

```
select count(enq.`enquiryId`),Month(enq.`date`),Year(enq.`date`) from enq where enq.date =YEAR(NOW()) GROUP BY MONTH(enq.`date`)
```